# Anaconda on Windows 10: iPython and Spyder fail to start in Python3 environment

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-10, anaconda

I'm using Windows 10 and I have Anaconda with Python 2 installed, so my root environment is Python 2. I created an additional Python 3 environment and among other packages installed iPython and Spyder into it. I used the Anaconda Navigator to install the packages.

I can activate and deactivate the environment using Windows CMD just fine. After activating the Python 3 environment in the CMD the ipython command typed into the same CMD starts up Python 3.6.1.

The Anaconda Startmenu folder does contain shortcuts to iPython and Spyder both for Python 2 and Python 3 now. I can use those to start both for Python 2 as before, but the Python 3 versions won't start. And there is no error message or crash or anything.

When clicking on the Python 3 iPython shortcut a command prompt pops up for a split second and immediatly closes again. Spyder does not even open a command prompt, it does absolutely nothing, I presume it's because iPython fails. Checking the task manager shows that there is no Python running in the background at all, so it really does not start.

Now I know that iPython 3 itself is not broken because I can start it from within CMD after switching environments, nonetheless I deinstalled and reinstalled them both, no change.

I then went into the shortcut to get the exact command it was executing to write a small batch file with a pause command to see if anything gets displayed when iPython fails. Doing a right-click on the shortcut and executing "open file location" leads me to `python.exe` in the Python 3 environment base folder, and executing that works fine of course.

So now I'm stumped since I have no leads to solve or even analyze the problem properly, over the entire course of action not a single error message ever appeared anywhere.

Any hints and suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT:

The target of the Python 3 shortcut in the properties looks like this:

`C:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\Python3\python.exe C:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\cwp.py C:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\Python3 "C:/Users/My.Name/AppData/Loca`

The working shortcut to Python 2 looks pretty much the same:

`C:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\python.exe C:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\cwp.py C:\Users\My.Name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2 "C:/Users/My.Name/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda2/pyth`

Comment: Rather than "Open File Location", right-click then choose "Properties" and see where the shortcut points. That will give you a better idea of the command

Comment: Thanks, that helps, also edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

As it turns out the module `menuinst` wasn't automatically installed into the new environment so I had to manually install it. Now everything works.